# Tell view to use another string for a specific property in the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have the following classes:

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
}

public class Dog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string SuperPowers { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose I have the following View:

```html
@model ViewModel
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Dogs.Count(); i++)
{
    <div class="dog">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Dogs[i].Id)
        <div>Dog name: @Model.Dogs[i].Name</div>
        <div>Dog type: @Model.Dogs[i].Type</div>
        <div>Dog super powers : @Model.Dogs[i].SuperPowers</div>
    </div>
}
```

**Question:** How can I specify to use `string "d"` for `Dog` class so that the html output looks like this:

```html
<div class="dog">
    <input type="hidden" id="d_0__Id" name="d[0].Id" value="1" />
    <div>Dog name: Boby</div>
    <div>Dog type: Turbo</div>
    <div>Dog super powers : Extra speed</div>
</div>

<div class="dog">
    <input type="hidden" id="d_1__Id" name="d[1].Id" value="2" />
    <div>Dog name: Lasy</div>
    <div>Dog type: Powered</div>
    <div>Dog super powers : Extra strength</div>
</div>
```

Notice the input has name `d[1].Id`

instead of `Dogs[1].Id`

I know I can later write a custom model binder to work with such html output, but it would be great if I didn't have to.

**IMPORTANT**

I am looking for a solution that will allow me to keep using `@Html.HiddenFor(...)` rather than `@Html.Hidden(...)` because I hate magic strings. I would welcome a solution even more if it did not include writing custom model binder to then interpret new html markup into a model.

In perfect case it would be an attribute of some kind that I would slap on my class. Example: `[BindClassNameTo(Name="d")]`

Comment: why not just write the actual html you want in the view instead of using the helper?

Comment: BTW, naming in view comes not from class, but from property name. Should you rename your viewmodel property from `Dogs` to `d`, you'd get what you want.

Comment: I understand that. The main reason I'd like to keep properties named properly and use something shorter in the html is that working with properly named properties is a lot easier on the back end. However, having a complicated models makes it is harder to read and work with html. `Category[5].Type[6].City[7].Person[3].Dress[0].Id` is harder to read than `c[5].t[6].c[7].p[3].d[0].Id`. This is a personal preference and may be different for somebody else.

Comment: Backend has nothing to do with views. That's why there's a concept of viewmodel (as opposite to *model*). The former is just for the sake of presentation, while the latter is used in processing.

Comment: thanks, I know. Unfortunately websites cannot be written without one of these.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Html.Hidden(string.format("d[{0}]", i), Model.Dogs[i])`

Comment: Thanks you for your input. However, I'd rather avoid using `Html.Hidden(...)`. I have updated my question to reflect this requirement.

Comment: @Dmitry You *are asking* for magic strings, and yet you hate them.

Comment: if these magic strings are bound to model automatically - they are not magic anymore.

Comment: @Dmitry binding is plain another question. What you have here is html generation. Binding from `POST` request generated by such markup would be as easy as specifying your parameter in action as `IEnumerable<Dogs> d`.

Comment: you are welcome to edit the question to reflect the requirements as you now understand them.

Comment: @Dmitry I suppose that there's no need. It quite clearly specified as "How can I specify ... so that the html output looks like this". You were given answer for that too.

Comment: there is more to the question that just "what you want to see". Stop being a jerk and if you can't help, just move on